# Drupal Content Access Control

Tags: nodes, users

Exploring Drupal, so still lot of unknowns.

Drupal 7 out of the box can do the following :

- Authenticated users can create/edit/delete "their own" article content. - works out of the box
- Admin can create/edit/delete "any" article content - works out of the box.

Wondering if Drupal 7 out of the box can do the following?

- Authenticated users can "only" view their "own" article content. I only see the option "View Content" but it seems to be for "any user". So when the "auth user A" creates an article it's available for "any" user. Is there a way to restrict view. This goes for both published and un-published article.
- Does the access control extends to any content types as per above or custom code is required?

Thank you for your clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, no it does not. For that you need to use an add-on module:

- [Content Access Control Modules](https://www.drupal.org/module-categories/content-access-control)

> All the modules that implement an access control system.

- [Information on Access Control Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/602730)
- A web search for 'drupal access control' will yield thousands of sites, tutorials, videos and other useful information.

Comment: Thank you Geoff. Do you use it in production? I read in description "Drupal 7 version of Content Access is not yet considered stable"

Comment: well, that's one major problem with contributed modules, the contributor stops contributing - the last update was two years ago, so there isn't likely to be any more updates coming. There are other options if the `beta` is concerning, but I have personally used it without issue on production sites, as have thousands of other people